# Reprovisioning server with PHP AWS SDK2 script

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

Since I got tired of repetitively clicking/waiting/clicking with Amazon web services GUI interface, I needed an EC2 script to:

1. Stop the instance specified at bash command line
2. Detach a specified volume
3. Create a new a volume from a specified snapshot
4. Start the instance up again

It can of course be done with the GUI, but its such a pain. This way I can just let the script run for 5 minutes while I get coffee instead of having to attend to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax:

```
php reprovision.php i-xxxx vol-xxxx snap-xxxx
```

reprovision.php:

```
<?php

require 'aws.php';

$config = aws_setup();
$ec2Client = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($config);

$stop = $argv[1];
$detach = $argv[2];
$snapshot = $argv[3];


$ec2Client->stopInstances(array('InstanceIds' => array($stop)));

sleep(60);

$ec2Client->detachVolume(array('VolumeId' => $detach));

sleep(10);

$vol = $ec2Client->createVolume(array('SnapshotId' => $snapshot, 'AvailabilityZone' => 'us-east-1a'));

sleep(10);

$ec2Client->attachVolume(array('VolumeId' => $vol->VolumeId, 'InstanceId' => $stop, 'Device' => '/dev/sda1'));

sleep(10);

$ec2Client->startInstances(array('InstanceIds' => array($stop)));
```

'aws_setup()' gets the configuration array to launch the ec2 client in the next line.

The command-line arguments are then assigned to variables.

The next version of the script would ideally use the EC2 wait functions instead of PHP's 'sleep'.

[AWS PHP SDK2 EC2 Client API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html)

Comment: The github link is broken.

Comment: @AndyHayden Thanks I have removed the broken link.